# Raycast hitting collider of character inconsistently, but hitting everything else consistently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, raycasting, collider

I'm making a FPS game, and I'm trying to write a method which detects when the enemy can see me.
I do this using raycasts.

**I have an issue where the raycast is not always hitting the (huge) box collider I expect it to always hit.**

The raycast happens from my AIShooting script, and I expect it to hit the box collider of my character.

The AIShooting script looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AIShooting : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject _playerCharacter;        //reference to the player controlled character
private CharacterController _playerCharacterController;
private Collider _characterCollider;
private GameObject _characterWeapon;        //reference to the weapon held by the AI
private int _offSetY = 1;                   //offset from player controlled character pivot point, so it shoots the character in the center
                                            //private LineRenderer _lineRenderer;   

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    _playerCharacter = GameObject.Find("Character");
    _playerCharacterController = _playerCharacter.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    _characterWeapon = _playerCharacter.GetComponent<Character>().EquipedWeapons[0];
    _characterCollider = _playerCharacter.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    this.transform.LookAt(_playerCharacter.transform);
    LookForEnemyByShootingRayCast();
}

void LookForEnemyByShootingRayCast()
{
    Vector3 _shootTarget = new Vector3(_playerCharacter.transform.position.x, _playerCharacter.transform.position.y + _offSetY, _playerCharacter.transform.position.z);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, _shootTarget, out hit, 10000))     //if the ray cast collides with object
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(this.transform.position, _shootTarget, Color.red);           //make the ray cast visible in scene view
        if (hit.transform.name == _characterCollider.transform.name )   //if the raycast hits the character collider
        {
            Debug.Log("THE ENEMY SEES YOU");
        }
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }
}
}
```

I make the raycast visible with a `Debug.Drawline()`, and it looks like this.
The ray is shot from the character on the right to the character on the left (with the huge box collider).

However, the line `Debug.Log("THE ENEMY SEES YOU");`is only triggered when I'm really, really close to the enemy character, and even then, it happens on certain locations and not consistent at all.

[image: Raycast display]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using if (hit.collider == _characterCollider) instead of comparing by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Physics.Raycast() method takes a direction as second parameter, instead of a target position
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
The Debug.DrawLine() works, because it takes two positions instead of position and direction.

You can calculate the direction like this

```
Vector3 _shootTarget = new Vector3(_playerCharacter.transform.position.x, _playerCharacter.transform.position.y + _offSetY, _playerCharacter.transform.position.z);
Vector3 _direction = _shootTarget - this.transform.position;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I must have been confused because of the way the `DrawLine()` method works.
Works as expected now!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck and have fun with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old, but I just spent a long time figuring out that any kind of raycast to hit a collider attached to an object with a non-kinematic rigidbody AND A NAVMESH AGENT will return extremely inconsistent hits. The rigidbody should be kinematic in this case.

Comment: You hero!  I've been banging my head against this.  For those of us who are noobs, what are the consequences of setting IsKinematic to true on that rigidbody?